# JQuery multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML markup:-

```
<select name="List1" id="l1">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
</select>  

<select name="List2" id="l2">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
</select>
```

Using the following Jquery:-

```
$('#l1 option:nth-child(n+5)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1">');

$('#l2 option:nth-child(n+5)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1">');
```

I want to transform this to use one Jquery line to handle both additions of the

So using this:-

```
$('#l1 option:nth-child(n+5), #l2 option:nth-child(n+5)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1">');
```

Seems to wrap all of the elements combined in both select lists.

I want the above to wrap the elements of each select list individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `wrapAll` but not wrapping all the elements...

You must use two selectors, or use one selector with `end` which is not the best practice...

`wrapAll` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.